# Python: create new column from existing and add generated numbers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string

The DataFrame looks as follows:

| atom_type | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N | 15.987990 | 10.554990 | 3.897990 |
| C | 16.980990 | 9.479010 | 3.851010 |
| H | 17.943000 | 9.921000 | 4.110000 |

I need to create a new column called `atom_label` that will consist of `atom_type` and a number ranging from 1 to 32. For now I tried to do it in such a way:

```py
atom_numbers = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 32, step = 1)
df['atom_label'] = str(df['atom_type'] + str(atom_numbers.item))
```

but it doesn't seem to work as I hoped so, it populates the column `atom_label` with string `N<built-in method item of numpy.ndarray ...`. I can't seem to be able to tell Python to pair a value from an existing column with *next* value from an array and put it in a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert values of `Series` to strings:

```
atom_numbers = np.arange(start = 0, stop = len(df), step = 1)
df['atom_label'] = atom_numbers

df['atom_label'] = df['atom_type'].astype(str) + df['atom_label'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# init dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["atom_type"] = ['N', 'C', 'H']

# init suffixes
atom_numbers = np.arange(start = 0, stop = 32, step = 1)

# add column
df["atom_label"]=[str(df["atom_type"][i]) + str(atom_numbers[i]) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Using your solution would always reuse the first value of the `atom_type` column, and `atom_numbers.item` is a method so calling `str(method)` will return something like `<method name, package, a.s.o ...>`.

In the above solution, we loop through all the values in your columns and numpy array to build a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The `item` is a method which needs the index you're referring to as argument.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html

You can use a for loop:

```
for i in range(0, atom_numbers.size):
    df['atom_label'][i] = str(df['atom_type'][i] + str(atom_numbers.item(i)))
```